# constructor CircularQueue in class CircularQueue cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, class, oop, object

Error:

```
QueueTestHarness.java:19: error: constructor CircularQueue in class CircularQueue cannot be applied to given types;
            testC[1] = new CircularQueue(SIZE);
                       ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
2 errors
```

I understand this means I don't have a constructor taking in a parameter (`int`) but in my class I do:

```
 public Queue(int inMax)
      {
          queue = new Object[inMax];
          int count = 0;
      }
```

Also `CircularQueue` is a subclass to `Queue` and here's proof of that in my code:

```
public class CircularQueue extends Queue
```

So why is this error popping up?

*Note*: I also do have a **default** constructor and it seems to work fine.

Comment: `CircularQueue` doesn’t have a constructor accepting `int`, just because the superclass has it. You have to declare it explicitly, i.e. `CircularQueue(int inMax) { super(inMax}; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dude, Queue is an interface which means if u want to use it (abstraction) to your class u have to use `implements` keyword

the `extends` works for extending of a Class... but Queue is an interface
your code is extending Queue and it is wrong

use this:

`public class CircularQueue implements Queue`

and don't forget to implement all Queue methods or make your class abstract

and one more thing

your constructor of CircularQueue is wrong

change it to this:

```
public CircularQueue(int inMax)
      {
          queue = new Object[inMax];
          int count = 0;
      }
```

your error is for this problem that when u have a Class with constructor ...
the constructor MUST be same name with Class name

but in your example Class name is `CircularQueue` but the constructor name is `Queue`

Comment: but it works perfectly with my default constructor that takes in no parameters?